# c++ destructor doesn't delete the object itself, what does?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, scope, destructor

Firstly, unless I've misunderstood it, a destructor frees up memory taken up by variables inside the object. In the below example it would delete the string pointed to by * str. That's ALL.

```
class StrPtr {
private:
    string * str;

public:
    StrPtr() : str(new string()) {} 
    
    ~StrPtr() { delete str; }
    void add(char c) { str->push_back(c); }
};
```

However, here's my confusion. If the destructor doesn't destroy the object itself. Does that mean:

1. After the for loop I have 10k StrPtr objects.
2. As soon as the for loop ends, the 10k StrPtr objects are deleted as they fall out of scope.
3. each time the someF() function finishes execution, the object is deleted, as it falls out of scope. Since this is where it was created. This is my thinking currently.

```
    void someF() {
        StrPtr s;
        s.add('a');
    }
    
    int main() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            someF();
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: If it isn't deleted, it leaks.

Comment: Your loop will enter `someF` 10000 times, each time it creates a `StrPtr`, adds `'a'` to it, then destroy that `StrPtr` when the function returns to the main loop. In this code you have at most 1 `StrPtr` in existence at a time. Edit : This is your case #3.

Comment: See: [automatic storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)

Comment: No leaks here. But `StrPtr` doesn't respect rule of 5/3/0 (copy/move constructor/assignment).

Comment: @tkausl That only applies to objects created with `new`.  `s` in `someF` wasn't.

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess I misunderstood the question. I thought OP was talking about what happened when he _does not_ delete `str` in the destructor. Well...

Comment: Destructors aren't responsible for destroying the object they are called on. They are *part* of the process of destroying the object. They are the part that performs any special custom cleanup the object needs. The actual object's destruction has already begun by the time the destructor is called. Whoever or whatever caused that destructor to be called is responsible for the rest. In the case of objects with automatic storage duration like `StrPtr s;` calling the destructor and the rest of the steps are done automatically when the object goes out of scope.

Comment: If you had written `StrPtr s, t; t = s;` then the behaviour of your code would have been undefined. This is a very good reason not to use bare pointers as class members. And study @Jarod42's comment carefully.

Comment: There is *no memory leak* in the code as it currently stands. And the behaviour is well-defined too.

Comment: Most/all of your confusion would be cleared up with a simple `std::cout << "ctor\n";` in the constructor of your class, and `std::cout << "dtor\n";` in the destructor of your class.

Comment: When an object is destroyed, the destructor is called first. Its actually a beforeDestroy() function. You get to do some things in the dtor (such as release resources which wont be let go by default, etc). Then, the language does its thing which is to call the destructors on the contained objects and then make the memory listed as free again. (And when the memory is released to the OS eventually, the OS may zero out the memory before making it available to other processes.)

Comment: @Jarod42 could you elaborate on the rule of 5/3/0? Do you mean the class lacks a copy, and assignment operator?

I just removed those for brevity, I know how to do those.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux "The actual object's destruction has already begun by the time the destructor is called"

This was my thinking before posting. I think I understand it now. What's calling the destructor and deciding that the object should be destryed is calculated automatically on stuff like whether it's in scope.

Comment: @Bathsheba thanks for pointing that out. I believe the solution to that is to create a custom assignment operator that properly copies the value stored at the location pointed by the existing pointer.

Comment: @Shiny_and_Chrome Regarding your reply to Jarod42's comment, yes, that was the point. It is a common error for novices to implement a destructor but to neglect the copy constructor and assignment operator while the compiler generated version is almost always wrong if you have to define a destructor.

Comment: See [rule_of_three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See option 3 on my question.

There are no memory leaks, there is never more than one StrPtr object in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need to pick up the difference between 'delete', 'deallocate' and 'destroy'. The thing that could help you is the observation that

```
{
    A *a = new A;
    ...
    delete a;
}
```

actually works like this:

```
{
    A *a = static_cast<A *>(std::malloc(sizeof(A)); // allocate
    new (a) A(); // construct [placement new, something like a->A()]
    ...
    a->~A(); // destroy
    std::free(a); // deallocate
}
```

So, 'delete' means 'destroy', then 'deallocate'.
Respectively, 'create' means 'allocate', then 'construct'.

In this scheme, (std::malloc, std::free) could be substituted with any other allocation strategy -- take a look on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits .
The same applies for allocation on the stack.

```
{
    A a;
    B b;
    ...
}
```

may look like this:

```
{
    // push %rbp
    // mov  %rsp, %rbp
    A *pa = <magic> // sub $sizeof(A), %rsp; pa <- %rsp
    B *pb = <magic> // sub $sizeof(B), %rsp; pb <- %rsp
    A &a = *pa;
    B &b = *pb;
    ...
    pb->~B();
    pa->~A();
    <deallocate everything>
    // mov  %rbp, %rsp
    // pop  %rbp
}
```

If you want to understand the magic of stack allocations, you'd better study the basics of assembly -- you will also get a notion of call frames, calling conventions and many other things that you usually have to memorize instead of deducing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'm vaguely aware of call frames, stacks, heaps and calling conventions, and I did do a bit of assembly on a arduino.

Your answer, while informative, might be a bit overly complex though. I've got the hang of it from the other replies.